# Comprehensive list of Python protocols/interfaces

Tags: python, interface, protocols

Lately, I was looking at some Python idioms.
I found many descriptions of protocols used in Python, such as the ordering (`__cmp__`, ...) or generators. Besides, there are also methods like `__hash__` which are defined for every object (I suppose).

After some search on the internet, I haven't found a comprehensive list of these protocols and methods.
Can anyone give me some <strike>pointers</strike> URLs?

Comment: FYI they're often called "magic methods".

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your best reference is always going to be the [Python Online Documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/contents.html), specifically the section on [Special method names](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-names).

The interactive Python interpretor is a very useful tool, too. Try some of these:

```
>>> dir(object)
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__']
>>> help(object.__class__)

>>> help(object.__hash__)

>>> help(hash)
```

Answer (score 10):

*UPDATE: this function will now traverse an object's subclass chain and extract ALL abstractmethods.  To use the old behavior, set `nested=False`.*

By convention, protocols are groups of special methods that describe common behaviors.  You can *roughly* infer protocols from the abstract methods  of the [`collections.abc`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/_collections_abc.py) module (Python 3.3+); see also the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html?highlight=abc#module-collections.abc).  Automate this listing with the following:

**Given**

```
import abc

import collections as ct
```

**Code**

```py
def get_protocols(source=ct.abc, nested=True):
    """Return a dict of protocols from source abstractmethods only."""
    dd = ct.defaultdict(set)

    for objname in dir(source):
        if objname.startswith("_"):
            continue

        obj = getattr(source, objname)
        classes = obj.__mro__ if nested else [obj]

        for cls in classes:
            if cls is object:
                continue
            abmethods = sorted(cls.__abstractmethods__)
            if not abmethods:
                continue    
            dd[objname] |= set(abmethods)        
    return dict(dd)
```

**Demo**

```
get_protocols()
```

Output

```
{
 'AsyncGenerator': {'__aiter__', '__anext__', 'asend', 'athrow'},
 'AsyncIterable': {'__aiter__'},
 'AsyncIterator': {'__aiter__', '__anext__'},
 'Awaitable': {'__await__'},
 'ByteString': {'__contains__', '__getitem__', '__iter__', '__len__', '__reversed__'},
 'Callable': {'__call__'},
 'Collection': {'__contains__', '__iter__', '__len__'},
 'Container': {'__contains__'},
 'Coroutine': {'__await__', 'send', 'throw'},
 'Generator': {'__iter__', '__next__', 'send', 'throw'},
 'Hashable': {'__hash__'},
 'ItemsView': {'__contains__', '__iter__', '__len__'},
 'Iterable': {'__iter__'},
 'Iterator': {'__iter__', '__next__'},
 'KeysView': {'__contains__', '__iter__', '__len__'},
 'Mapping': {'__contains__', '__getitem__', '__iter__', '__len__'},
 'MappingView': {'__len__'},
 'MutableMapping': {'__contains__', '__delitem__', '__getitem__', '__iter__', '__len__', '__setitem__'},
 'MutableSequence': {'__contains__', '__delitem__', '__getitem__', '__iter__', '__len__', '__reversed__', '__setitem__', 'insert'},
 'MutableSet': {'__contains__', '__iter__', '__len__', 'add', 'discard'},
 'Reversible': {'__iter__', '__reversed__'},
 'Sequence': {'__contains__', '__getitem__', '__iter__', '__len__', '__reversed__'},
 'Set': {'__contains__', '__iter__', '__len__'},
 'Sized': {'__len__'},
 'ValuesView': {'__contains__', '__iter__', '__len__'}
}
```

<sub>NOTE: When sub-classing, these are (required) abstract methods that do not include the mixin methods.  Example: sub-classing `collections.abc.Mappings` will provide methods `.keys()`, `.values()`, `.items()` (no listed) once the protocol is implemented.</sub>

<sub>NOTE: Only abstractmethods are listed.  Some methods are excluded, e.g. `close()` on all generator-like functions.</sub>

Comment: An answer so uniquely useful, it's worth bookmarking.